# Light/Color tracking using webcam

Tags: java, linux, api, webcam

I am trying to create a program that tracks a coloured LED through the webcam (whether by color or by light) but I am having trouble finding a platform independent API for such a project. I am currently using a linux machine and have found nothing that seems to works for my needs. CV seems to not work in linux and windows at the same time so I am stumped. Does anyone know of a Java API that works in this case? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: invoke webcam in Java.
You could use [webcam-capture library](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture)

step 2: processing image in Java.
You could use [JavaCV](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/)